# Error when using flutter's video_player to access RTSP stream

Tags: flutter, dart, rtsp, exoplayer, flutter-video-player

I'm trying to access a RTSP stream using a flutter app. The code shown here is a modified version of the module's example (available [here](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)).

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoApp());

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'rtsp://192.168.101.202:554/profile1')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _controller.value.isInitialized
              ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
          )
              : Container(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

On 192.168.101.202:554 I have a simple camera, that can be accessed without a password. The backing player behind the video_player module is ExoPlayer, which, according to its documentation, should be able to handle RTSP streams (the documentation can be found [here](https://exoplayer.dev/rtsp.html)). I've also checked and the camera feed format is supported by ExoPlayer. When I press play, I get the following error on my console:

```
E/flutter (23004): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
```

I've tried checking the documentation for some answers, but I've had no success so far. Is there a way to fix this error or is my camera feed somehow unsupported?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: hi, flutter is still using old version of `ExoPlayer` and it doesn't support `RTSP`.
I'm facing same issue, did you solve this? would you share your solution please?

Comment: @DNS I used the Flutter VLC package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player). Just as a heads up: if your app crashes on release mode using the VLC package please refer to this (https://github.com/solid-software/flutter_vlc_player/issues/160#issuecomment-768985811).